Contract reverts at deploy when sending 2 ethers
This contract deploys fine when no value is added and get reverted when I try to send 2 ether on the remix VM.......which is exactly the opposite of what I expected or should be happening.  I retraced all the code and try debugging but no luck.   Thank you.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract FundMe {
    function fund() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= 1e18, "You need to spend more ETH!");
    }
} 


If you want to pass the value while deployment, then you need to make the constructor() as payable, like this:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract FundMe { 
   constructor() payable {
        require(msg.value >= 1e18, "You need to spend more ETH!");
    }
} 


thank you! I appreciate it!

You’re welcome. Happy to help.
